# C - Create dynamic matrix with values

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic

i try to create dynamic matrix and enter values with scanf.
Its work only for 1 row, when i increase the error begins.
Can not make progress from the first line and thus can not get values.

```
int main()
{
    int **matrix1;
    BuildMatrix(&matrix1, 3, 3);

}

void BuildMatrix(int*** matrix, int row, int column)
{
    int i, j, flag = 1, num;
    *matrix = (int**)malloc(row * sizeof(int*));
    if (*matrix == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < row && flag; i++)
        {
            *matrix[i] = (int* )malloc(column * sizeof(int));
            if (*matrix[i] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Not enough memory!\n");
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    free(*matrix[j]);
                    flag = 0;
                }
                free(*matrix);
            }

        }
        if (flag)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < column; j++)
                {
                    scanf("%d", &*matrix[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: matrix1 needs just 1 '*' which can be passed directly into BuildMatrix

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve]. And don't forget to *tell* us what errors or problems you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the expression `*matrix[i]` is equal to `*(matrix[i])`. That is, it dereferences `matrix[i]` and not `matrix`.

You need to use `(*matrix)[i]` instead.

Comment: @דורסויסה Yes. Including `*matrix[i][j]` which should be `(*matrix)[i][j]`.